# Illustrator - Recolor text with 2 different colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I have a piece of text that uses a 2 different colours, one for the titles and one for the paragraphs. Is there any way the colours can be edited using something like Recolour Artwork, so that you don't have to select the single pieces but just change the colours in the block of text.

[image]

Comment: I think I just found the solution. Just need to save the colours in the swatches and set them as global

Comment: Protip: Use paragraph/character styles.

Comment: @Adrian using global swatches isn't a bad idea, you should add it as an answer to the duplicate